# Changing style of SVG elements in a g group using JS

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Can I change the css style, such as fill or stroke, for all elements within a g group using JS?
Here's the svg, script and the external css:

```
<g id="trajectories" class="trajectory">
    <circle id="tr1" cx="0" cy="0" r="75" />
    <circle id="tr2" cx="0" cy="0" r="110" />
    <circle id="tr3" cx="0" cy="0" r="160" />
    <circle id="tr4" cx="0" cy="0" r="230" />
    <circle id="tr5" cx="0" cy="0" r="350" />
    <circle id="tr6" cx="0" cy="0" r="475" />
    <circle id="tr7" cx="0" cy="0" r="625" />
    <circle id="tr8" cx="0" cy="0" r="750" />
</g>

function mouseDown() {

    svgElement = document.getElementById("trajectories");
    svgElement.style.stroke = "Black";

}

g.trajectory{
    fill: none;
    stroke: rgba(30,30,30,1);
    }
```

The circles in the g inherit the fill and stroke of the class g.trajectory when first drawn, but attempting to change the styling of the g element does nothing. I could change the styles of the circles individually, but is it possible to change them all just by targeting the g element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried targetting the `circle` with straight `css`?

I.E

`g circle {color:#ff0000;}`

On the fiddles below i added a little bit in between your circle tags just for demo purpose

Here is a fiddle of this http://jsfiddle.net/vTNrR/

Or with jquery

```
$('#trajectories circle').css('color','#ff0000');
```

Here is a fiddle of the JQuery approach http://jsfiddle.net/vTNrR/4/

Or with javascript

```
var svgElement = document.getElementById("trajectories"); // get the parent node
var circles = svgElement.getElementsByTagName('circle'); // get child nodes
```

You now have an array of elements in `circles` so can do something like

```
for (var i=0;i<circles.length;i++)
{ 
  circles[i].style.color="#ff0000";
}
```

Here is a fiddle of the pure JS version http://jsfiddle.net/vTNrR/1/

Comment: Cool. If it works and answered your Q, please do mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work.  It works for me.  See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cSk3f/

However you are changing from dark grey to black, so the change is not very noticeable.  So in my demo I have used green (`rgb(30,80,30)`) instead.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be a browser issue, with Opera the child elements do not seem to inherit the changed style from the g element for some reason, but with Firefox it works...